# Espresso Nested Recycler Views UI testing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, ui-testing, android-espresso

I have a Horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a vertical `RecyclerView`. I'm using this code I found on other question:

```
onView(allOf(isDescendantOfA(withRecyclerView(R.id.parentVerticalRecyclerView).atPosition(parentPosition)),
             isDescendantOfA(withRecyclerView(R.id.childHorizontalRecyclerView).atPosition(childPosition)),
                (withText("USA"))))
                .perform(click());

// It is not working for parentPosition > 0
```

but this only works for first row of parent `RecyclerView`.

How do I click on the element on the child RecyclerView of the second row of parent `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution for this:

```
onView(allOf(
         withId(R.id.childHorizontalRecyclerView),
         withParent(
           withRecyclerView(R.id.parentVerticalRecyclerView).atPosition(2)
         )
       )
).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(3, scrollTo()))
.check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("USA"))));
```

Comment: What was the issue with initial matcher?

Comment: I think the issue was that I was using isDescendantOfA. Espresso wasn't able to find the view.